# Calling Objective c method in swift app

Tags: objective-c, swift

Okay I've got the bridging Header all set up and I can now use my objective c code but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use objective c methods in swift.

This is the method in my .m file that I imported

```
 -(void)sendWithLoadMessage:(NSString *)loadMessage
         successMessage:(NSString *)successMessage
         failureMessage:(NSString *)failureMessage
        recoveryOptions:(NSString *)recoveryOptions
                success:(void (^)(CustomResponse *response))success
                failure:(void (^)(CustomResponse *response))failure
```

and here is how I use it in my objective c app. I need to know how to do this in swift:

```
CustomRequest *request = [_user login];
    [request sendWithLoadMessage:@"Signing In"
    successMessage:@"Signed In"
    failureMessage:@"Failed to log in"
    recoveryOptions:@"try again"
    success:^(CustomResponse *response) {
        ....

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an Objective C Method in swift, you need to treat the method like a Swift function. You call functions on an instance through `.`

For you, it would be like this:

```
let request = _user.login
request.sendWithLoadMessage("Signing In", successMessage: "Signed In", failureMessage: "Failed to log in", recoveryOptions: "try again", response: { CustomResponse in
    println(response) 
})
```

**Taking advantage of trailing closures here:**

```
let request = _user.login
request.sendWithLoadMessage("Signing In", successMessage: "Signed In", failureMessage: "Failed to log in", recoveryOptions: "try again") { response: CustomResponse in
    println(response) 
}
```

**Using the `$` syntax, you can make this even shorter by doing it this way. If you already know the parameters passed back in the block, you can access the list of parameters without typing it out by calling `$indexOfParameter`. The $ syntax is 0 indexed so your first parameter would be $0, your second parameter would be $1, etc.**

```
let request = _user.login
request.sendWithLoadMessage("Signing In", successMessage: "Signed In", failureMessage: "Failed to log in", recoveryOptions: "try again") {
    println($0) 
}
```